# Imported jars with null pointer methods

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a method on my service, where I included a packaged (that is in a jar) from other libraries (that I cannot modify).

So, the included packages are in other contexts (I can reach them because they were included on my pom).

At the end, the problem is this.

On the class myService I have

private SomeService someService;

```
private boolean doSommething() {
    try {
        success = someService.somemethod();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        ...
        }
    }
    return success;
}


 @Required
 public void setMyService(SomeService someService) {
     this.someService = someService;
 }
```

From my app, I always get `someService` as null. Is there anyway to configure this to make it work? Like a bean configuration or something?

Answer (score 0):

In your bean definitions, add this:

```
<bean id="someService" class="SomeService"/>

<bean id="myService" class="MyService">
    <property name="someService" ref="someService"/>
</bean>
```

Make sure the method name in MyService is:

```
setSomeService(SomeService someService)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, is there anyway I can do this with annotations?

Comment: Yes.. you can @Autowire SomeService in MyService as well.. but if you do, make sure the MyService is a bean too.

Comment: The answer below would be correct if you are looking for annotation based solution

Answer (score 0):

With annotation you can inject the dependency like below

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class CallingService {


    @Autowired
    protected SomeService someService ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot modified that code, is not possible for me to set the @Autowired

Comment: then go for xml based injection

Comment: If the calling service, calls many others more jars with all these others services and all, will the @Autowired work?